# Parse SQL query output to unknown class using annotations

Tags: java, sql, mapping

I am trying to make a database parser for practice and I want more information on how I would parse SQL query output to a java class.

Example class:

```
public @interface Field { public String value(); }

class Foo {

  @Field("id")
  public int Identifier;

  @Field("bar")
  public String Bar;

}

public class DatabaseHandler {

  public ? get<?>(int id) {
  // I wouldnt know how to start here
  }

}
```

What I would like to archieve is a method in my `DatabaseHandler` that maps a SQL querie to above classes. These are typed out and obviously not in correct Java syntax.

I would call it with

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler();
Foo foo = db.get<Foo>(1);
// and probably later
List<Foo> foo = db.getList<Foo>();
```

Where would I need to start with this? Could someone write a quick example and maybe give some links to documentation?

I've build this in C# the other day which is a lot easier then Java. But I get the idea of mapping data.

Comment: Writing a SQL parser is inline with writing a parser for any programming language.  So, you should research on this to start.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did but I couldn't find much honestly. So that is why I came to stack overflow

Comment: Asking  how to write a complete SQL parser is too broad for Stack Overflow's format.